# OpenGL clips an object for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, perspectivecamera

I'm trying to visualize a simple quad made of -1 to 1 vertices along x and y axis. Why opengl clips the object? The code seems correct to me

```
glm::mat4 m = glm::translate(glm::mat4{1.0f}, toGlmVec3(objectPosition));
glm::mat4 v = glm::lookAtLH(toGlmVec3(cameraPosition), toGlmVec3(objectPosition), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
glm::mat4 p = glm::perspective(glm::radians(50.f), float(640.f) / 480.f, 0.0001f, 100.f);
glm::mat4 mvp = /* p* */ v * m; // when I take p back, the object disappears completely

testShader.use();
testShader.setVector4("u_color", math::Vector4f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f));
testShader.setMatrix4("u_mMVP", mvp);
```

in shader's code only a line

```
gl_Position = u_mMVP * vec4(a_Pos, 1.0);
```

[image]
after moving the camera a bit along z axis
[image]

if I comment out `v *`, then it works fine and object moves along x and y axis on the screen

without view matrix, only model:
[image]
move the object along x and y
[image]

so it looks like the rendering code is working fine but what is wrong with view and projection matrices?

Comment: my projection was `RH` by default, however, i explicitly used `LH` for `lookAt`. That caused the problem of the object being not visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object is clipped by the near and far plane of the [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection). If you don't explicitly set an projection matrix, the projection matrix is the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix). The near plane far pane are at +/- 1.

Use [`glm::ortho`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00243.html#ga6615d8a9d39432e279c4575313ecb456) to define a different projection matrix. e.g.:

```cpp
glm::mat4 p = glm::ortho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -10, 10);
```

The orthographic projection matrix defines a cuboid viewing volume around the position of the viewer. All geometry outside of this volume is clipped.

Comment: @Herrgott There is always a projection and clipping. Projection and clipping cannot be turned off. I've changed the answer.